# Strange WIFI behavior on WPA2 Enterprise network

Tags: networking, wireless, wireless-adapter

I spent most of last night trying to manually config the WIFI to automatically connect to my University's WPA2 Enterprise network using the RP2 w/ the Edimax EW-7811Un. I finally got the wpa_supplicant to behave correctly with all the correct credentials and it turns on automatically on boot, but I'm having some strange issues with RX packet loss. For example when I ping some server like google, the packets take forever to send. Mind you the ping time is very quick around 20ms or so but the time it takes to either send the request or receive the packet back is very long. When I do an ifconfig the only strange thing I see is (on wlan0)

```
RX packets:198 errors:0 dropped:152 overruns:0 frame:0
```

The dropped packets are where I think I'm getting the huge latency. (There are no dropped packets on the TX side btw) Now normally you would think this is a network problem but I'm on my laptop on the same network and I'm getting no packet loss at all. Does anyone have an idea of what is going on here? Running iwconfig the quality reports

```
Link Quality=100/100 Signal Level=70/100 Noise Level=0/100
```

Could the signal level have anything to do with it? I can't imagine it's causing a 76% packet loss, right?

Comment: Is your RPi the client, or are you using it as a router/firewall to connect other devices behind the RPi? Are you noticing any difference in the packet loss between internal (LAN) and external (Internet) targets?

Comment: @bobstro I'm using the Pi as a client. The only time I'm connecting to it is if I want to ssh into it. I can do that but it's slow as well. If that's what you mean by LAN (connecting to devices through the same router), then it's still slow. If you mean LAN as in connecting to the router through a wired connection, I have no access to that. There is no cat5e LAN socket in my room (that I see at least haha)...

Comment: So from your computer to RPi via wifi is also slow, correct? I've used that same wifi adapter on older RPis with no issues, but there is the possibility that your power supply could be weak. Do you notice a rainbow square at top-right of your display? Do you see the loss when you do a simple `ping` between your computer and RPi?

Comment: @bobstro It might be important to point out that on my home network using a WRT router the the raspberry pi has no packet loss or noticeable latency when using SSH, so I think we can rule out the wireless adapter malfunctioning at least on a hardware level. Also I do not see a rainbow square at the top right of my desktop. So anyways, when I go to ping the device I get very little packet loss if none at all, at least from what the ping command shows, although I do notice that the ping times are very inconsistent, ranging from 3ms to 250ms, which is strange. Any other tests you might recommend?

Comment: Try pinging local and Internet IPs with varying packet sizes. (e.g. `ping -s 1024 8.8.8.8`) Do you get loss at smaller and larger packet sizes, particularly at 1.5K size, or at all sizes? Varying timing that much is odd, although wifi *is* subject to a lot of factors.

Comment: @bobstro Interesting. When I ping 8.8.8.8 with the regular 56 bytes of data my timing is pretty consistent around 40ms with 0% packet loss. Same with 128bytes, 256bytes, 512bytes, and 768bytes. When I get to 1024 however, the packet loss climbs to 26% with an average timing of 106ms. 1280bytes gets a packet loss 14% (oddly). BUT, when I get to 1536 or above, there is 100% packet loss. This is after 50 packets all these tests were done. Interesting you mention 1.5K because that's exactly where it broke. Any significance to that value?

Comment: Tried some more IP's. 4.2.2.2 is really reliable at low levels but if you bump it up to 4096 you get 50% packet loss. Seems like when connecting to an Internet IP the packet loss goes way up the bigger the packet. Though when I tried connecting from the Pi to my laptop's IP locally I see the same thing I saw when I tried to connect to the Pi, a highly variable ping time. On top of that when I change the size the packet, loss goes up as well. Using the 4096 packet size connecting to a local IP I get a 52% packet loss just as if I was connecting to an Internet IP...

Comment: When it tanks at 1500, that's an indicator that MTU discovery is broken. Over-enthusiastic firewall admins often shut off too much ICMP traffic. If that's the case, though, I'd expect your RPi and computer to have the same issue, and it's usually a hard drop at 1.5K. What OS is your computer? Keep in mind that your Internet target (e.g. google at 8.8.8.8) might also start choking ping traffic. Maybe you can do a `traceroute` and repeat the pings to some of the network equipment outside your room? Are you running iptables on your RPi by any chance?

Comment: My laptop is on OSX 10.9.5. My laptop also fails at 1.5K on 8.8.8.8, although when I switch to just pinging google.com's IP, it goes through fine, and when I bump it up to 4096 bytes I get no packet loss and a consistent ping time. On the RPi though the same ping command puts the packet loss at 52%. Traceroute to something on same network (let's say xx.xx.1.117) goes from my IP (xx.xx.46.198) -> (xx.xx.46.1) -> (xx.xx.1.117) end.  Pinging the IP in the middle (xx.xx.46.1) I get really consistent times and 0% packet loss. For interest, my laptop ifconfig looks like [this](pastebin.com/yyLrG7DG)

Comment: I do use IPtables on the RPi but all that is listed is 
    `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target   prot opt source   destination
    Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
    target   prot opt source   destination
    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target   prot opt source   destination`

Comment: If you're getting pings with > 1.5K size through, it's not MTU discovery, so you've eliminated that. When you get much larger than that, a lot of providers will drop your ping traffic, so don't worry about those 4K drops. Sounds like you can ping anything on your university network without packet loss. You only experience loss on your RPi to Internet addresses, correct? Nothing comes to mind.

Comment: Ugh I don't know what is going on still. SSH performance is unexplainably better, but connecting an Internet address is slow.... but here's what confuses me. Okay so I connected my laptop to the RPi through SSH and executed a ping to google [here](http://pastebin.com/41kbMYpW). Simple, right? So you can see there is only 7 packets sent which isn't a lot, but look how long it actually took to do the test. 26.2 seconds... 0% packet loss but it took so long... no idea why...